# 3D Slitherlink (Slithersurface)

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional, slitherlink

Here is a 5 x 5 x 5 cube filled with numbers.
It's a 3D adaption of standard slitherlink puzzles.
You must create a solid 3D object such that the number in each sub-cube matches the number of adjacent faces.
You can assume that the surface will never touch itself except at connections.

[image]
I'm 90% sure that this has a unique solution.

It might very well be possible to remove some numbers and still have a valid solution, but since this is a new puzzle type (as far as I know) I'll give all the information.

Please let me know what you think and most importantly, have fun!

Comment: Just to be clear, the layers are meant to be stacked left to right (so the lower-left layer is adjacent to the top right layer), correct?

Comment: That is correct, I'll add layer numbers shortly :)

Comment: My apologies, I just discovered some errors in layer 1. They are now fixed. I hope this doesn't set anyone back too far!

Comment: Layer 2 needed fixing too, it should all be correct now

Comment: As a side note, the 3d slitherlink has been done before in MIT Mystery Hunt, 2016 (http://web.mit.edu/~puzzle/www/2016/puzzle/cubism/)

Comment: @phenomist Very cool. I'll give it a try! Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I started from the top layer, and the rest soon fell into place.
>  
>  [image: GRATS]

Comment: Congratulations! When I tested it I began from the bottom.

Comment: Quite a fun puzzle. I enjoy Slitherlink, and this was a tough one. Having all the clues present made filling the remaining layers much easier than the first layer, but the first layer was really difficult.